# Comparing 5 Integers in least number of comparisons

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have this code and need to make sure that all result variables are equal?

```
long result1 = timer.CalculateElapsedTimeInMinutes();
long result2 = timer.CalculateElapsedTimeInMinutes();
long result3 = timer.CalculateElapsedTimeInMinutes();
long result4 = timer.CalculateElapsedTimeInMinutes();
long result5 = timer.CalculateElapsedTimeInMinutes();
```

This is what I did, but I feel like it can be done in a simpler way, maybe not?

```
bool allEqual = (result1 == result2) && (result3 == result4) && (result1 == result3) && (result1 == result5);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Close votes!!! What's wrong with these idiots? You must be feeling 
SO powerful!! A perfectly valid question here.

Comment: Well, crucial details were added after the initial post. As I saw it, this was a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534748/design-an-efficient-algorithm-to-sort-5-distinct-keys-in-fewer-than-8-comparisons By the time I had tracked down that question, and pasted the URL in the close dialog, the text of this question had changed. So, I am one of the idiots.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's *just* about possible that there's some hacky/clever bit-twiddling way of doing this with XORs or something - but your code makes it clear what you want to do, and will still be ridiculously fast. The chances of this becoming a bottleneck are close enough to 0 to not be worth considering IMO - so go with the most readable code.

I would be a bit more consistent in your comparisons though:

```
bool allEqual = (result1 == result2) && 
                (result1 == result3) && 
                (result1 == result4) &&  
                (result1 == result5);
```

It's easier to see visually that you've got all the bases covered, IMO.

Comment: I see, I will make the change. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Nope, you're going to require at least *n*-1 comparisons.  Though I'd write it like this:

```
bool allEqual = (result1 == result2)
             && (result2 == result3)
             && (result3 == result4)
             && (result4 == result5);
```

Comment: and so you might as well make the code really clear by simply comparing result1 with each of the other values in turn.

Comment: @Kip agreed. Apparently, transitivity of equality is too hard for some.

Comment: I like the cyclical symmetry here. Comparing one result with every other isn't any more or less clear in my opinion, the difference is purely aesthetic.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that's pretty much perfect.

> Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler.  -- Albert Einstein

Comment: It's a good quote, but he's about the last person I'd expect to hear it from ;).

Comment: @Hadryv,  what Einstein did could be (and often is) characterized as one of History's most significant and most elegant simplifications.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with link using the All extension method.

```
        var results = new long[] {
            timer.CalculateElapsedTimeInMinutes(),
            timer.CalculateElapsedTimeInMinutes(),
            timer.CalculateElapsedTimeInMinutes(),
            timer.CalculateElapsedTimeInMinutes(),
            timer.CalculateElapsedTimeInMinutes()
        };

        bool allEqual = results.All(x => x == results[0]);
```

Comment: Now timer.CalculateElapsedTimeInMinutes() stands out like a sore thumb :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way it might be faster is to short-circuit it in such a way that the pair most likely to be different is evaluated first.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the heck of it, would this work ?

```
  bool allequal =
       res1 & res2 & res3 & res4 & res5 == 
       res1 | res2 | res3 | res4 | res5;
```

only *one* comparison... `<grin>` (if you don't count the bitwise operations!)

Comment: although it's 9 operations now, as opposed to 7. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this with LINQ:

```
var firstValue = timer.CalculateElapsedTimeInMinutes();

var list = new List<long>();
list.Add(timer.CalculateElapsedTimeInMinutes());
list.Add(...);

bool allEqual = list.All(i => i == firstValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by comparison. You can do it using only one explicit comparison operaor:

```
bool result = 
    ((result1 ^ reesult2) | (result1 ^ result3) | (result1 ^ result4) | (result1 ^ result5))==0;
```

This *might* even have an advantage in the generated code -- the code using the logical and is required to stop doing comparisons as soon as it finds any un-equal value. That means each comparison has to be done individually, and it has to include code to quit the testing after each comparison.

Unless you're doing this inside a really tight loop, however, it's not worth it -- just do what you find the most readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a helper function for this:

```
bool AllEqual<T>(params T[] values) where T : IEquatable<T> {
    // make a decision here and document it
    if (values.Length < 1) return true; // I guess?

    bool result = true;
    T first = values[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++) {
        result = result && first.Equals(values[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```